# no matching function call to ctor, multiple inheritance

Tags: c++

I am very desperate my other classes which have the same inheritance works, this class that I have written was just so simple, it no longer works. I don't know what to do, this is very very frustrating, in fact it is simple class that defines the enemy which do simple predetermined behavior upon their creation.

```
#include "RD_Infested.hpp"
#include "World.hpp"
#include "SteeringBehavior.hpp"

RD_Infested::RD_Infested(const string& oname, const sf::Vector2f& position, esc::World & w )
   : esc::Critter(oname , position, w),
     esc::Offensive(*this)
{
    esc::Critter::setPathTraversalPolicy(new esc::SteeringBehavior(*this));
}

RD_Infested::~RD_Infested()
{
}

void RD_Infested::update( float e )
{
     if (!esc::Object::isActive() )
         return;

     esc::Offensive::executeAttackOrder( e );
     esc::Offensive::executeDefensiveStance( e );

     if ( !esc::Offensive::isOnAttackRange() )
        esc::Critter::makePursuit( e );

     esc::Critter::getPathTraversalPolicy()->updatePolicy( e );
}

RD_Infested* RD_Infested::getInstance()
{
    return this;
}
```

Here its class header:

```
#ifndef RD_INFESTED_HPP
#define RD_INFESTED_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "Critter.hpp"
#include "Offensive.hpp"

class RD_Infested : public esc::Critter,
                    public virtual esc::Offensive
{
    public:
        RD_Infested( const string&, const sf::Vector2f&, esc::World& );
        virtual ~RD_Infested();

        virtual void update( float = 0.0f );
        RD_Infested* getInstance();
};

#endif // RD_INFESTED_HPP
```

So what this class does is to inherit from Critter which is a moving object and Offensive being its behavior so in turn conceptually it becomes 'an Offensive Critter'.

This is the error it gives me:

```
   error: no matching function for call to 'esc::Behavior::Behavior()'|
```

Here is Offensive class: I have removed the unnecessary functions

```
#ifndef OFFENSIVE_HPP
#define OFFENSIVE_HPP

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include<stack>
using std::stack;

#include "Behavior.hpp"
#include "Weapon.hpp"

namespace esc
{
    class World;
    class Object;
    class Critter;
    class Manager;
    class AttackCapability;

    // Worlds

    class Offensive : public virtual Behavior
    {
    public:
        /****/

    protected:

        explicit Offensive( Critter * );
        virtual ~Offensive();

    private:
        /****/
    };
}

#endif // OFFENSIVE_HPP
```

And here is Behavior class:

```
#ifndef BEHAVIOR_HPP
#define BEHAVIOR_HPP

#include<stack>
using std::stack;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include "Critter.hpp"

namespace esc
{
class World;

class Behavior
{
    protected:

        explicit Behavior( Critter * );
        virtual ~Behavior();

    /****/

    private:
        /****/
    };
}

#endif // BEHAVIOR_HPP
```

This one error I do not know how to fix. I did my research about having default ctor being generated but I still don't know or even understand this kind of problem. I don't know how to fix this one.

Thanks. :)

Comment: A default ctor is only generated if the programmer provides no ctors.

Comment: yeah I didn't provide a default ctor, but why is it generating? I am already proving arguments for my Offensive class already. I am actually thinking that when RD_Infested is an Offensive Critter, as you can see, first Critter is being constructed, next Offensive which receives a pointer to Critter class hence the this. I know there is ugliness going on in my code here but this error will not make me sleep this night.

Comment: Offensive inherits Behavior and calls its ctor. You don't call one explicitly so the default one is called. But Behavior has no default ctor. That's what the error message is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: no matching function for call to 'esc::Behavior::Behavior()'|

Some part of your client probably code tries to create a `TestConstructDerived` instance using its default constructor.
This default constructor is defined (since it's not disabled by the definition of a constructor with arguments or by `= delete`), but the default constructor for `Offensive` isn't, since it has a constructor with arguments defined.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559503/call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-in-llvm) for details about the conditions under which default constructors are defined.

Comment: Yeah, this is it. Some part of the code causes this error. Thanks for that link too!

Answer (score 2):

Your `Offensive` constructor expects a pointer to a `Critter` object:

```
explicit Offensive( Critter * );
```

but you pass an object to it

```
esc::Offensive( *this )
```

as `this` is a pointer and you dereference it. So just use `esc::Offensive(this)`. But the next point is that this might not be a good idea to pass a `this` pointer to a base class constructor in the constructors initializer list of the derived class.

Comment: Wow! How can I miss that? Thanks, but also why is it not good idea? Before all this, I have made a hierarchy which is very ugly, its very restrictive. It doesn't provide me flexibility so I decoupled offensive from that hierarchy and decided to treat them as behaviors for my entities. Now my entities inherit what they want to become, a doodad or critter and they can inherit a behavior if they want to attack, create or support. My behavior class technically needs information on its host. This is the reason why I did it. Thanks for the heads up on the don'ts. :P

Comment: I still got the same error. What causes this kind of error?

Comment: The problem is that in the constructor initializer list the object is not properly initialized and passing a `this` to an other object allows him to access any uninitialized members or call functions that return the value of an uninitilized member.

Comment: If you still have the error you might have defined an other class that inherits from Behaviour and tries to call its default constructor as you perhaps forgot to explicit call the appropriate constructor (as Martin J. indicated). The error message should mention where the error occured.

Comment: Both of you had the same answer. That's awesome, some part of the hierarchy one of my entities RD_Worker is non virtually inheriting from Creative class. This might have caused the problem as you may have thought of. Thank you very much! I have yet to compile and debug some lines of codes until then I never know if I got the desired behavior. Thanks to you again. :)