# LLVM find_if implicitly-deleted copy constructor with unique_ptr<>

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, llvm, unique-ptr

So I'm working through a book about game development with SFML and C++11, and one of the lines of code used to create a scene tree is giving me trouble that is a little over my head at this point. The compiler is returning an error due to an implicitly deleted copy constructor of the unique_ptr in the find_if algorithm.

Here's the function with the find_if call. Ptr is a typedef for a `std::unique_ptr<SceneNode>`. This is the only place where I use find_if currently.

```
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::detachChild(const SceneNode& node) {
    auto found = std::find_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), [&] (Ptr p) -> bool { return p.get() == &node; });

    assert(found != mChildren.end());

    Ptr result = std::move(*found);
    result->mParent = nullptr;
    mChildren.erase(found);
    return result;
}
```

The error returned is brought up within the algorithm itself, and is specifically "call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Ptr'."

There is a related question located at [Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559503/call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-in-llvm), but the answer isn't making much sense in my case.

As a note, I'm using the latest Xcode 5 release for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda expression in the `find_if` call takes a `Ptr` (aka `unique_ptr<SceneNode>`) argument by *value*, which means it's attempting to copy the `unique_ptr`; `unique_ptr`s are non copyable, hence the error.

Change the lambda expression to the following:

```
[&] (Ptr const& p) -> bool { return p.get() == &node; }
//       ^^^^^^
// take the argument by reference and avoid copying
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! This was my first interaction with lambda expressions, and so I borrowed the line straight from the book. Time to read up more on them it seems.

Comment: @gelliott181 Another tip: you can drop the `-> bool` part because C++11 allows the compiler to infer the return type for lambda expressions that consist of a single return statement such as the one you have.