# Vector of objects with a unique_ptr member and custom destructor

Tags: c++, c++17

Assume the following piece of code to move an object of type `A` into `av` (vector):

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    ~A() {};

    std::unique_ptr<int> an_int;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<A> av;
    av.push_back(A());

    return 0;
}
```

This will fail to compile as is. However if I do not implement the destructor `~A() {}`, it will work just fine. The compiler hints at some missing (deleted) `copy constructor`, but I fail to see where that applies here (as I am only doing move operations)

What is the relationship between the `unique_ptr` and the custom destructor that makes the code fail to compile? is there a simple work around for this?

Thanks.

Comment: `push_back` makes a copy, maybe you're thinking of `emplace_back`. The compiler generated copy constructor is missing because you can't copy a unique_ptr.

Comment: @MarkRansom there is an overload for `push_back` for rvalue references, which *moves* the element instead of copying.

Comment: In addition to answers below, see slide #30 [here](https://accu.org/content/conf2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf).

Comment: At the very bottom of [this page](https://howardhinnant.github.io/classdecl.html), Howard Hinnant has a helpful table of special member functions that get implicitly defaulted, deleted or inhibited when the user declares other special member functions.  (That's the same as slide #30 that HolyBlackCat linked.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a custom destructor disables generation of the default move constructor and move assignment operator. Thus `push_back(const A&)` is used, but `A` does not have copy constructors either since it has `unique_ptr` member.

The solution is to manually define them as `default`. But defining the move constructor disables the default constructor:

```cpp
struct A
{
    ~A() {};
    A()=default;
    A(A&&)=default;
    A& operator=(A&&)=default;
    std::unique_ptr<int> an_int;
   
};
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<A>);
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<A>);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define a destructor the compiler does not generate a move/copy constructor since you just hinted that the construction/destruction of the object is not trivial. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559684/390913).